# How to implement for approval model on laravel nova

Tags: laravel-nova

I have resource `Post` and after create or update, this post data moving in approval model.

And the approval have status: `reject`, `revision` and `approved`.

how to implement in approval model, because i have tired. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resources use [Model Events](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/#resource-events) because Nova is using Eloquent.

So assuming you're managing a status with a select:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Nova;

use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Select;

class Post
{
    public function fields()
    {
        return [
            ...

            Select::make('Status')->options([
                'approved' => 'Approved',
                'rejected' => 'Rejected',
                'revising' => 'Revising',
            ]);
        ];
    }
}
```

You would then listen to a post's status upon `saving` by [listening for that event:](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#observers)

```php
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Post::observe(PostObserver::class);
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

class PostObserver
{
    public function saving($post)
    {
        if($post->status == 'approved') {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

It is worth noting, `saving()` catches the post before it is `saved()`

You can hook onto these statuses within the [Observer](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#observers) and perform more behavior.

So if you wanted to create an additional model when status changes:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

class PostObserver
{
    public function saving($post)
    {
        if($post->isDirty('status')) 
        {
            Approval::create([
                'post_id' => $post->id,
                'user_id' => auth()->id(),
                'status' => $post->status,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Or any task related to the status change, for example sending mail:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

class PostObserver
{
    public function saving($post)
    {
        if($post->isDirty('status') && $post->status == 'rejected') 
        {
            Mail::to($post->author)->send(new PostRejected($post));
        }
    }
}
```

Although, if you have an Approval model.. I'd say put that in the ApprovalObserver in `created`

---

~  Brian Dillingham ([@im_brian_d](https://twitter.com/im_brian_d))